# Is an expressed value itself an expression?

Tags: expression, programming-languages, semantics

[Essentials of Programming Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=GtPoyremy4EC&pg=PA71&dq=%22the%20expressed%20values%20are%20the%20possible%20values%20of%20expressions.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivu8rH9_3jAhXHT98KHYDIBY0Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20expressed%20values%20are%20the%20possible%20values%20of%20expressions.%22&f=false) says that

> the expressed values are the possible values of expressions, and the denoted values are the values
>   bound to variables.

Is an expressed value itself an expression?

If a value is not an expressed value (e.g. if a value is a denoted value  but not an expressed value), can it be an expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value is an expressed value if there is an expression that evaluates to it, right? So let's say a value is an expression, then there'd be at least one expression that evaluates to (namely the value itself). That makes it an expressed value.

So every value that is itself an expression is necessarily an expressed value.

Comment: Thanks. Is an expressed value itself an expression?

If a value is not an expressed value (e.g. if a value is a denoted value but not an expressed value), can it be an expression?

Comment: "Is an expressed value itself an expression?" It can be (or, depending on how you look at it, there can be an expression that always evaluates to that value and whose syntax is the same as the string representation of the value), but it doesn't have to be. For example not every language has a literal expression for arrays. "If a value is not an expressed value (e.g. if a value is a denoted value but not an expressed value), can it be an expression?" Isn't that exactly the question I just answered?

Comment: I meant "If a value is not an expressed value" while you replied "If a value is  an expressed value"

Comment: @Ben I think you misread my answer. I said "If a value is an expression, then it is an expressed value" (from which immediately follows that there can't be a non-expressed value that is an expression), not "If a value is an expressed value, ...". Unless I'm completely missing something, that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468823/are-the-denoted-values-and-the-storable-values-the-same?